# Form submit button will not submit when name of button is "submit"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, submit

I am having trouble getting a form to submit when the name attribute of the submit button is precisely "submit".

Here is the code:

`<input onclick="checkForm(document.form_29) && document.form_29.submit();" value="Submit" name="submit" type="button">`

Note that we are not using a standard input type of "submit", but rather an input type of "button" with JavaScript being used to submit the form after a validation script (checkForm) has returned true.

The odd thing is that this will not work if and only if the name attribute is "submit". The problem is case-sensitive, so the following (and any other naming, including no name attribute) will work:

`<input onclick="checkForm(document.form_29) && document.form_29.submit();" value="Submit" name="Submit" type="button">`

I have been looking over the W3C specs for some mention of a reserved name, but I could not find anything. I suspect I am overlooking something really obvious here, so I'm hoping some of y'all out there can see something I can't.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: better to go with `type="submit"`

Comment: Yeah - I would like to, but I can't - I won't go into the reasons why - it is a long story, and it is not a decision I can make.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're having issues because the `name` being `submit` is overriding the `form.submit()` function reference for that `<form>`, instead `form_29.submit` refers to that button, rather than the DOM `submit()` function.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks! Pretty sure that is the answer...

Comment: Yes, this is all Netscape's fault for originally deciding that form fields should be reflected as named properties on the `form` object, rather than just the `form.elements` collection where you'd expect them. This, as well as the reflection of named elements on `document` (and, in IE's even-worse case, `window`) has caused endless problems. We can never be free of this foul mis-design now. Damn their fat, `<blink>`​ing faces.