# Submitting a form from inside a JavaScript function in Tapestry

Tags: javascript, tapestry

I am trying to submit a form from inside a JavaScript function in Tapestry. 
Here is the tml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd" xmlns:tx="tapestry-library:tapx">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function bodyLoaded () {
          document.form1.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyLoaded()">
<form t:type="form" t:name="form1">
    <select t:type="select" t:id="reportType" t:model="literal:A, B"></select>
    <input t:type="submit" id="clientSubmit" value="Generate"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting below error, and the form is not getting submitted.

> document.form1 is undefined [Break on
>   this error] document.form1.submit();

So I looked at the html code generated by Tapestry. It has following tag:

```
    <form onsubmit="javascript:Tapestry.waitForPage(event);" 
  action="test.form" method="post" id="form" name="form">
```

So I changed document.form1.submit() to document.form.submit(), but still it didn't solve the problem. Is there anything wrong with my code (or) doesn't hibernate allow to submit the form from inside JavaScript functions?

Comment: I got the problem now. Tapestry created submit button with the name "submit". And javascript was getting confused between submit button and submit() function. After I removed the input field, it was working fine. So the solution is not to use Tapestry input field, and but to use <input type="button ..." (if you want to call submit() from inside javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade to tapestry 5.2. this was a known issue in prior 5.x versions.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-947

Answer (score 0):

```
<form t:type="form" t:name="form1" t:id="form1">
    <select t:type="select" t:id="reportType" t:model="literal:A, B"></select>
    <input t:type="submit" id="clientSubmit" value="Generate"/>
</form>




<script type="text/javascript">
        function bodyLoaded () {
          document.getElementById('form1').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

i have just put id in the form tag and one change in java script.

This may help you.

Thanks.

Comment: It didn't help. :( with "form1" as the form name, I got error "document.getElementById("form1") is null". With "form" as the form name, I got error "document.getElementById("form").submit is not a function"

Comment: ok..try to add one more form element 'method="post"'.its may be work.

Comment: Tapestry generated this code "<form onsubmit="javascript:Tapestry.waitForPage(event);" 
  action="test.form" method="post" id="form" name="form">". It is POST only.

Comment: ok..i think i got the point. your function is called when the page is loaded.but at that time your HTML form is not created. so please remove bodyLoaded function from onload event. put this function on click event on any button.it may work.

Comment: I have to call the submit function from body onload function only. It is a long story. :(

Comment: Oh!. then you have to create your form by JavaScript first and then submit your created form.i don't think there is any alternative for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `document.form` try `document.forms[0]`

Comment: Didn't work. Got this error, "document.forms[0].submit is not a function". I realized one thing now. The tag that generated for the input field is "<input id="clientSubmit" value="Generate" name="submit" type="submit">". This may be the culprit. The button name should not be "submit". Since the button name is "submit", it is not able to call "submit()" function.  Here is the link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571328/form-submit-button-will-not-submit-when-name-of-button-is-submit

Answer (score 0):

```
Use id of the form

<form t:type="form" t:name="form1" t:id="form1">

document.form1.submit();
```

Comment: got the error, "document.form1.submit is not a function
[Break on this error] document.form1.submit();" Earlier the error message was "form1 is undefined". With this change, the error is "form1.submit is not a function".

Comment: document.form1.submit();
In this form1 is a id of form

Answer (score 0):

I updated tapestry today from 5.0.1.5 to 5.0.1.8 to get rid of the annoying bug in AjaxFormLoop, and guess what I ran into :)
After being frustrated for almost 4 hours I tried something that worked.

The error is caused by Tapestry automatically adding a waitForPage(event) javascript method on the form's onSubmit event (to prevent the form from being submitted before the page is loaded). When you say `document.getElementById('form1').submit();` or any of its iterations suggested by the comments here, it seems to throw that exception because of a mismatch in the method arguments (I think). Anyway to fix it just change the line to `document.getElementById('form1').submit(this);`

This worked for me and I hope this solves your problem as well!