# submit form on click event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So can someone please tell why neither of these options will actually submit the form?  I am trying to do something more complicated but I have boiled it down to this to try and figure out why I can't seem to get this form to submit using a click event and submit()

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#testForm").submit();
    });

   $('#submitLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#testForm").submit();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="javascript:alert('submitted');" method="post" id="testForm">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    <p><a href="#" id="submitLink">Submit Form</a></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a form action and an input `type="submit"` inside form tags, it's going to submit the *old fashioned way* and basically refresh the page.  When doing AJAX type transactions this isn't the desired effect you are after.

Remove the action.  Or remove the form altogether, though in cases it does come in handy to serialize to cut your workload.  If the form tags remain, move the button outside the form tags, or alternatively make it a link with an onclick or click handler as opposed to an input button.  Jquery UI Buttons works great in this case because you can mimic an input button with an a tag element.

Comment: The action is just something I was using to test to see if the form was submitting, which it was not.  In my actual code I am not doing an AJAX type transaction, I am submitting the form to the server and processing it with php.  But before it gets processed I am using the Facebook api to see if the user wants to submit their post to their facebook wall as well.  So, in effect, I need to give them time to response before it submits.  The strange thing with the two examples I have above is neither one actually submits the form at all which makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'd imagine it'd be easier to do the Facebook check on the server side just prior to the form submit, then return false if the desired action is not submitting.

Comment: Ok now I get it, the submit button inside the form tagswas breaking it for both options.  When I remove the submit button, the link works as expected.  Thanks bpetersen!

Answer (score 14):

it's because the name of the submit button is named "submit", change it to anything but "submit", try "submitme" and retry it.  It should then work.

Comment: wait, what? why?... edit: [here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571328/form-submit-button-will-not-submit-when-name-of-button-is-submit). Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Why not simply use the submit button to run the code you want. If your function returns false, it will cancel the submission.

```
$("#testForm").submit(function() {
    /* Do Something */
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery button click

```
$('#button_id').on('click',function(){
     $('#form_id').submit();
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to post the the form to an URL or do you only need to detect the submit-event? Because you can detect the submit-event by adding `onsubmit="javascript:alert('I do also submit');"`

```
<form action="javascript:alert('submitted');" method="post" id="testForm" onsubmit="javascript:alert('I do also submit');">...</form>
```

Not sure that this is what you are looking for though.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Henrik but I do want to actually submit the form