# jQuery submit form with click event with new action

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

I am having a form like this

```
    <form name="test" action="test/test_new" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
<input type="button" value="download"/>
```

I need a click even for download button. Eg. If i click download it should submit as `text/text_new.xls` instead of `text/text_new`. How can i do it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Give id to button and try this

```
$('#downloadButton').click(function(){
  $('form[name=test]').attr('action','test/test_new.xls');
  $('form[name=test]').submit();
});
```

Comment: if input[type=submit] have id or name with "submit" value than such code is not working!!! Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6299551/987850

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<form name="test" id="form-id" action="test/test_new" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" class="submit" value="search" data-action="test/test_new" />
<input type="button" class="submit" value="download" data-action="test/test_new.xls" />
<input type="button" class="submit" value="another" data-action="test/test_newer" />
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.submit', function () {
    var form = $('#form-id');
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    form.attr('action', action);
    form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="download" id="dwnld"/>
```

**js**

```
$('#dwnld').click(function(){
var form = $(this).closest('form');
form.attr('action',form.attr('action')+'.xls').trigger('submit');
});
```

or

**HTML**

```
<form name="test" action="test/test_new" id="formID"/>
<input type="button" value="download" id="dwnld"/>
```

**js**

```
$('#dwnld').click(function(){
form=$('#formID')
form.attr('action',form.attr('action')+'.xls').trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: He said that he want to submit form to `text/text_new.xls` instead of `test/test_new`

Comment: any specific reason you using .`trigger('submit')` vs `.submit()` ?