# File upload with a submit button which has a different name

Tags: html, forms, servlets, file-upload, form-submit

This question may be connected to this Stackoverflow-question:

[Form submit button will not submit when name of button is "submit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571328/form-submit-button-will-not-submit-when-name-of-button-is-submit)

Well, I have a basic HTML formular for uploading files which is looking like this:

```
<form action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="uploadName" name="file">
    <button type="submit" id="uploadButton" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Now, when pressing "Upload" the file is correctly uploaded and processed. But when adding a name attribute to the submit button:

```
<button id="uploadButton" name="anyname" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
```

Then the request brokes (by using the TamperData plugin in Firefox is seems that the request is being sent as text/html instead of application/...). I tried to find some answers, but the only thing I found was the above mentioned question. I am not sure whether this question is connected to this. I strongly assume that the problem is assigned to "multipart/form-data", isn't it?

It also may be a servlet-problem: when using a name attribute for the submit button I am getting a NullPointerException in `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getString` (due to a request.getParts()-call).

Now that I've found the source of the problem I really want to understand it. Thanks for your replies :-)

Comment: are you using any other things for submission like form.submit()?

Comment: no, it's the same like this example...

Comment: Bootstrap may do something, I am not sure

Comment: try removing `class="btn btn-primary"` if the error persists then its nothing to do with bootstrap