# parsley.js validating but not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I am using the latest parsley release and It is validating my data fine just when the validation is complete its not submitting and I've been at this for hours now and am completely out of ideas as what is the cause. I am using integrated into a phpbb3 instance as it is needed for user validation as only logged in users should be able to do the survery which all works and when I disable validation the form submits as expected so its a problem with the validation i'm sure.

the code is here: http://pastebin.com/VJMVJHvP
any ideas or suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Next time, use `jsfiddle` or similar, so we can try it live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good thing you posted your code...

It turns out that [your input named `"submit"` is conflicting with the method of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571328/form-submit-button-will-not-submit-when-name-of-button-is-submit). Rename your submit button and everything will work.

Comment: Thanks I'll try changing the submit name to something else, and see if it will work.

Comment: Thanks that nailed it