# input type submit not pass the process to action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create 2 form stacking in 1 php code.
But the form cannot submit at all. It just sit there without passing this form to action="..."

Here the coding for first form (Registration)

```
<form id="RegForm" class="form" action="PHP/Enter_New.php" method="post">
<!-- Progress Bar -->
<ul id="ProgressBar">
    <li class="active">Access Code</li>
    <li>Account Setup</li>
    <li>User Agreement</li>
</ul>

<!-- Fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Are you lost?</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Get your access code before enter!!</h3>
    <input type="text" name="invite" class="invite field" placeholder="Access Code" onkeyup="checkAvAccess()" autocomplete='off' required />
    <br />
        <img src="/Images/Gif/Checking.gif" id="loaderIcon-access" style="display:none" />
        <span id="availability-status-access"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="login" class="action-button" id="toLog" value="Login" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" id="access" value="Next" disabled="disabled" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="title">Account setup</h2>
    <h3 class="subtitle">Login information</h3>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="username field" id="regUsername" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="checkAvReg()" autocomplete='off' />
        <img src="/Images/Gif/Checking.gif" id="loaderIcon-reg" style="display:none" />
        <span id="availability-status-reg"></span>

    <input type="password" name="password" class="password field" id="password" placeholder="Password" required />
        <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress"></div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" id="logInfo" value="Next" disabled="disabled" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">User Agreement</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">By signup at our website... </h3>        
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" id="subRegister" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"/>
</fieldset>
```

After registration form closing, there's no other code there.. The next code after that login code

```
<form id="LoginForm" class="form" name="login" action="PHP/Redirrect_to.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Enter Website</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Please login to continue!!</h3>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="username field" id="login" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="checkAvLogin()" autocomplete='off' required />
        <img src="/Images/Gif/Checking.gif" id="loaderIcon-login" style="display:none">
        <span id="availability-status-login"></span>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="password field" placeholder="Password" required />
        <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress"></div>
    <input type="button" name="register" class="action-button" id="toReg" value="Register" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" id="subLogin" value="Submit" formaction="PHP/Redirrect_to.php" formmethod="post" disabled="disabled" />
</fieldset>
```

note that Disable on submit input will be remove by js after onkeyup=".." value = true

The where you will see there's many next and previous because i'm using multistep form basic.  [Here the original code](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar). I have remove return false value from js

Comment: This is incomplete - this is just the HTML, where's the javascritp, and the PHP? And how does the register-bit get submitted? The action is for different PHP-files, so the question makes no sense in its current form.

Comment: Give both forms separate names and you determine which form was submitted based on if(isset($_POST['name']))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never name your submit button "submit"

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" ... />  <-- bad name

<input type="submit" name="anyNameButSubmit" ... />  <-- good name
```

[Form submit button will not submit when name of button is "submit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571328/form-submit-button-will-not-submit-when-name-of-button-is-submit)

Comment: Thanks Jeff McCloud, after removing name, I manage to pass the process to next form..

Comment: Awesome! can you mark the answer as "Answered" ?  thanks!